# How to Stop Pushing segue when some condition Happens?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

How to Stop Pushing segue when some condition is failed

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    internet *myclass = [[internet alloc]init];
    if ([myclass connectedToInternet]) {


    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showShoping"]) {
        _pass = @"shop";
        MyTabController *mvc = (MyTabController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        mvc.myCategory = _pass;
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showTravel"]) {
        _pass = @"travel";
        MyTabController *mvc = (MyTabController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        mvc.myCategory = _pass;
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showFood"]) {
        _pass = @"food";
        MyTabController *mvc = (MyTabController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        mvc.myCategory = _pass;
    }
    else{

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet!"
                                                        message:@"No working internet connection is found."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: you called this line **showShoping** in another place , can show that place or else are you using self.performsegue identifier in your current class show that code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it is storyboard Segue identifier , yes i am showing current class code

Comment: ya sudeer I know bro, in which method you called this segue, for ex login button pressed or else some where'

Comment: -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

Comment: apart from you called in anywhere bro

Comment: no . when we press button it is going to VC

Comment: show that button action bro , thats all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(nullable id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

you can override this method, return No to stop perform segue when some condition happens.

**for example**

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {



    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"showShoping" ]) {



        return NO;

  }
 return YES;

}

}
```